# How to play back a byte stream in libVLC for Android

Tags: android, libvlc

I would like to play back a byte stream with the media player in libVLC for Android. But I don't find any Interface or Class where I could "inject" a byte stream. Only chance I have for play back is providing a file descriptor, a path to a file, or an URI.

Android's native media player provides the interface **setDataSource(MediaDataSource dataSource)** where a byte stream can be injected by extending the class MediaDataSource. Do I have similar possibility in libVLC for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The libVLC API you are looking for is [libvlc_media_new_callbacks](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media.html#ga591c3cbe56444f1949165b2b9b75d8e2).

However, it seems it is not currently exposed to Java to be used with a Java stream parameter. This would need to be implemented by you in the libvlcjni bindings, I believe.

You could get inspiration from this existing code making use of that API

```
void
Java_org_videolan_libvlc_Media_nativeNewFromFdWithOffsetLength(
    JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject libVlc, jobject jfd, jlong offset, jlong length)
{
    vlcjni_object *p_obj;
    int fd = FDObject_getInt(env, jfd);
    if (fd == -1)
        return;

    p_obj = VLCJniObject_newFromJavaLibVlc(env, thiz, libVlc);
    if (!p_obj)
        return;

    p_obj->u.p_m =
        libvlc_media_new_callbacks(p_obj->p_libvlc,
                                   media_cb_open,
                                   media_cb_read,
                                   media_cb_seek,
                                   media_cb_close,
                                   p_obj);


    if (Media_nativeNewCommon(env, thiz, p_obj) == 0)
    {
        vlcjni_object_sys *p_sys = p_obj->p_sys;
        p_sys->media_cb.fd = fd;
        p_sys->media_cb.offset = offset;
        p_sys->media_cb.length = length >= 0 ? length : UINT64_MAX;
    }
}
```

https://github.com/videolan/vlc-android/blob/f05db3f9b51e64061ff73c794e6a7bfb44f34f65/libvlc/jni/libvlcjni-media.c#L284-L313

libvlcsharp has this implemented, including for Android platforms, but it's .NET.